# Linq with Optional Where clauses

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq statement which has two optional Where clauses but I cannot work out how to implement this linq (at the moment I have 4 linq statements in this method which off course is not good!):

```
//Params passed into my method:
int StoreId = 0;
bool ShowEnabledTills = true;

    var query = (from Transactions in db.Transactions
        join Tills in db.Tills on new { TillId = Convert.ToInt32(Transactions.TillId) } equals new { TillId = Tills.TillId }
         join CompanyAddresses in db.CompanyAddresses on new { CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(Transactions.StoreID) } equals new { CompanyId = CompanyAddresses.CompanyId }
         where
             CompanyAddresses.CompanyId == StoreId  <===== OPTIONAL
             && Tills.Active == ShowEnabledTills  <===== OPTIONAL
         select new
         {
             Tills.TillId,
             Tills.ComputerName,
             Tills.Description,
             CompanyAddresses.CompDescription
         }).Distinct();
```

I took a look at PredicateBuilder but I couldn't quite get my head around this but if I can create some re-usable code this would be great!

Comment: (CompanyAddresses.CompanyId == StoreId || StoreId = 0) ?

Comment: when you say "optional", do you mean the item should be selected regardless of that predicate is true or false?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler thats right.

Comment: isn't that the same as skipping the predicate then? or saying ( CompanyAddresses.CompanyId == StoreId || true) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get these from params to decide optional or not
    var validateStoredId = false;
    var validateActiveStatus = false;
```

And in your `where` clause do something like:

```
 where
     (!validateStoreId || CompanyAddresses.CompanyId == StoreId) 
     && (!validateActiveStatus || Tills.Active == ShowEnabledTills)
```

Comment: That's what I'd do, but I'd flip it so that the simpler expression is first.

Comment: I updated based on your comment Jim. I agree that's better.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little to contribute here I think. I came across the same problem, and implemented a similar solution. HOWEVER! This wont short-circuit as you would hope (or at least it didn't in mine!)

This led to me looping through a list of 10k items checking if true == false effectively, which whilst not an expensive check is a check you don't want to do thousands of times nevertheless.

For anyone else coming to this, I'd recommend splitting your queries down into subqueries wrapped in if checks, that is far more performant when dealing with large datasets :)

Edit : I built this little helper for doing exactly this, hope someone else finds it useful, I enjoyed not having to break my method chains :)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OptionalWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, bool excecuteFilter)
{
        if (!excecuteFilter)
        {
            return source;
        }
        else
        {
            return source.Where(predicate);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = db.Transactions.Join(
    db.Tills, //Join to this table
    transaction => transaction.TillId //Outer key
    , till => till.TillId, //Inner key
    (transaction, till) => new {transaction, till}) //Result of join
    .Join(db.CompanyAddresses, //Join to this table
    r => r.till.StoreId, //Outer key
    a => a.CompanyId, //Inner key
    (r, address) => new {r.transaction, r.till, address}); //Result of join

if(StoreId != null) 
    query = query.Where(d => d.address.StoreId == StoreId);

if(ShowEnabledTills)
    query = query.Where(d => d.till.Active == true);

var items = query.Select(d => new {
    d.Till.TillId,
    d.Till.ComputerName,
    d.Till.Description,
    d.address.CompDescription
    }).Distinct();
```

I did it without knowing much about your schema, but this should give you a good idea.

I disliked the "SQL style" syntax for this very reason (confusing at times). I started using method calls like this and never had a problem since.